# How to generate faster mysql query with 1.6M rows

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have a table that has 1.6M rows. Whenever I use the query below, I get an average of 7.5 seconds.

```
select * from table 
where pid = 170
and cdate between '2017-01-01 0:00:00' and '2017-12-31 23:59:59';
```

I tried adding a LIMIT 1000 or 10000 or change the date to filter for 1 month, it still processes it to an average of 7.5s. I tried adding a composite index for pid and cdate but it resulted to 1 second slower.

Here is the INDEX list
https://gist.github.com/primerg/3e2470fcd9b21a748af84746554309bc

Can I still make it faster? Is this an acceptable performance considering the amount of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the index is missing. Create this index and see if its helping you.

```
CREATE INDEX cid_date_index ON table_name (pid, cdate);
```

And also modify your query to below.

```
select * from table 
where pid = 170
and cdate between CAST('2017-01-01 0:00:00' AS DATETIME) and CAST('2017-12-31 23:59:59' AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: I already tried this but the result was 1 second slower (ave of 8.5s) so I deleted it.

Comment: Check this and let me know.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. There is a mysql error when I try to add the index with to_char. However, I am investigation a solution that would use the same idea as you are suggesting. Still working on it.

Comment: The index worked so I don't need the CAST sql part. I think the difference of my original implementation of the INDEX was that i used cdate first. In your INDEX, you used pid first which has a lower cardinality. The query is now around 290ms. Thank you!

Comment: @primerg - The rule is to put the '=' part first; 'range' last.  Cardinality does not matter.  More: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Thanks Rick it helps to know the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE clicks`.
- How many rows are returned?  If it is 100K rows, the effort to shovel that many rows is significant.  And what will you do with that many rows?  If you then summarize them, consider summarizing in SQL!
- Do have `cdate` as `DATETIME`.

Do you use `id` for anything?  Perhaps this would be better:

```
PRIMARY KEY (pid, cdate, id)  -- to get benefit from clustering
INDEX(id)   -- if still needed (and to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy)
```

This smells like Data Warehousing.  DW benefits significantly from building and maintaining Summary table(s), such as one that has the daily click count (etc), from which you could *very* rapidly sum up 365 counts to get the answer.

`CAST` is unnecessary. Furthermore `0:00:00` is optional -- it can be included *or* excluded for either `DATE` or `DATETIME`. I prefer

```
    cdate >= '2017-01-01'
AND cdate  < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

to avoid leap year, midnight, date arithmetic, etc.

Comment: Fyi this was already solved. My answer was clarified in the last 2 comment. But to answer your question, I updated the gist file with the show table results. Yes, we do use id as a reference to other tables. It returned 52k rows for the original query. Our data scientist was using this query to double check something so it's not often that they need to use this query.

Comment: @primerg - OK.  It is not wise to make significant changes to the table only to benefit rare queries.

Comment: Indeed but I was also curious. What could possibly go wrong when adding more indexes?

Comment: @primerg - Not a lot goes wrong with more indexes, and usually the issues are minor:  * downtime to add index; * slightly slower `INSERT` (etc); * more disk space used.